# Rotating around created vertices

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

i recently learn xna and is trying to create a room using vertices. I went and try out Riemeres XNA tutorial and learn alot but i can't seem to make my camera work well, every time i move left or right some of my image or textured seems to disappear and reappear. Please Help.

Here is my code.

```
public struct MyOwnVertexFormat
{
    public Vector3 position;
    private Vector2 texCoord;

    public MyOwnVertexFormat(Vector3 position, Vector2 texCoord)
    {
        this.position = position;
        this.texCoord = texCoord;
    }

    public readonly static VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration
         (
             new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
             new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 3, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0)
         );
}

public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    GraphicsDevice device;

    Effect effect;
    Matrix viewMatrix;
    Matrix projectionMatrix;
    VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;
    Vector3 cameraPos;
    Texture2D streetTexture;
    private Vector3 Position = Vector3.One;
    private float Zoom = 2500;
    private float RotationY = 0.0f;
    private float RotationX = 0.0f;
    private Matrix gameWorldRotation;
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth =1024;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
        graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        device = GraphicsDevice;


        effect = Content.Load<Effect>("OurHLSLfile"); SetUpVertices();
        SetUpCamera();


        streetTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("streettexture");
    }
    private void UpdateKeyboard()
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            RotationX += 1.0f;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            RotationX -= 1.0f;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            RotationY += 1.0f;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            RotationY -= 1.0f;
        gameWorldRotation =
            Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(RotationX)) *
            Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(RotationY));
    }
    private void SetUpVertices()
    {

        MyOwnVertexFormat[] vertices = new MyOwnVertexFormat[12];

        vertices[0] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(-20, 0, 10), new Vector2(-0.25f, 25.0f));
        vertices[1] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(-20, 0, -100), new Vector2(-0.25f, 0.0f));
        vertices[2] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(2, 0, 10), new Vector2(0.25f, 25.0f));
        vertices[3] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(2, 0, -100), new Vector2(0.25f, 0.0f));

        vertices[4] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(2, 1, 10), new Vector2(0.375f, 25.0f));
        vertices[5] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(2, 1, -100), new Vector2(0.375f, 0.0f));
        vertices[6] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(3, 1, 10), new Vector2(0.5f, 25.0f));
        vertices[7] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(3, 1, -100), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.0f));

        vertices[8] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(-13, 1, 10), new Vector2(0.75f, 25.0f));
        vertices[9] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(-13, 1, -100), new Vector2(0.75f, 0.0f));
        vertices[10] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(-13, 21, 10), new Vector2(1.25f, 25.0f));
        vertices[11] = new MyOwnVertexFormat(new Vector3(-13, 21, -100), new Vector2(1.25f, 0.0f));

        vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, MyOwnVertexFormat.VertexDeclaration, vertices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        vertexBuffer.SetData(vertices);
    }

    private void SetUpCamera()
    {
        cameraPos = new Vector3(-25, 13, 75);
        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPos, new Vector3(0, 2, -12), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
        projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1.0f, 5000.0f);
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();
        UpdateKeyboard();
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        device.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1.0f, 0);

        effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["Simplest"];
        effect.Parameters["xViewProjection"].SetValue(viewMatrix * projectionMatrix * gameWorldRotation);
        effect.Parameters["xTexture"].SetValue(streetTexture);

        foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();

            device.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
            device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, 0, 10);
        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's a projection issue. This line, taken from your code, strengthens my assumption:

```
viewMatrix * projectionMatrix * gameWorldRotation
```

**tl;dr**, the correct order is:

```
gameWorldRotation * viewMatrix * projectionMatrix
```

---

Please remember that order matters when multiplying matrices. In mathematical terms:

**Matrix multiplication is not commutative!**

Those three matrices map a vector to three different coordinate systems, the world, view and projection space. Usually vertices are defined in object space. Multiplying a vector with the world (view, projection) matrix brings your vector to world (view, projection) space:

```
object space => world space => view space => projection space
```

XNA uses a row vector layout (as opposed to column vectors). That means a vector is declared horizontally `(x, y, z)`. Skipping the [<strike>dry</strike> interesting details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), it means that when transforming a vector (multiplying the vector with a matrix), the *vector is the left operand*, while the *matrix is the right operand*:

```
A := [3x3 Matrix]

(x, y, z) * A = (x', y', z')  // The result is another 3D vector
```

Now in order to apply all three matrices we simply use the result of the previous transformation as input for the next transform:

```
W .... world matrix
V .... view matrix
W .... projection matrix
x .... vector
x' ... transformed vector

x' = ((x * W) * V) * P
```

Finally, **matrix multiplication is associative** (braces don't matter). And that's why we can combine the world, view and projection matrix into a single matrix before sending it to the device:

```
x' = ((x *  W) * V) * P  =  x * W * V * P  =  x * (W * V * P)
```

**World * View * Projection**. That's all you need. (And maybe some basic matrix math for your future work.)

Comment: Thank you for your help..i didnt realise order matter. You been a big help!